# Trouble understanding hash table theoretical complexity

Tags: hashmap, time-complexity, computer-science

I have trouble understanding the complexity of a hash table, from  a theoretical perspective.
I have to add that i do not have formal training in CS, so my question might be trivial, or ill formed.

To be more precise, i can understand the O(1) lookup time expected performance -and the magic of transforming algorithms from O(n^2) -> to O(n) using this scheme.
But, i have trouble accepting this complexity from a theoretical point of view. That is, in theory, the time complexity of an algorithm -the formula that is-  should be independent from the size of the input. But, a hash table is, to my understanding, not in depended, or to be even more precise, it could be in depended given infinite memory.

The necessary rehashing of the table, when used in practice, is, again to my limited understanding, a consequence of this fact, that in principle a hash table needs either infinite memory -irrespectivly of the size of the input- , or a bounded input. But, then, the notion of complexity should be loosened a little bit.

So, i would understand as a more precise answer a list deduplication algorithm using a binary tree with O(nlogn) complexity than a list deduplication algorithm using a hash table with O(n) complexity.

My question is how the CS community views this category of algorithms, from a theoretical prerspective, and a possible reference that i could/should use to understand the subject better.

Comment: The way I interpret your question, it is analogous to the question of random-access memory in an algorithm. Random access allows you to retrieve elements from a simple array by their index in constant time, yet it's independent of the size of the array. Not all computing models provide random access, so you may gain/lose a factor *n* just depending on the computing model. Hash tables, in turn, also rely on random access for their *O(1)* lookup time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're thinking in **the** right direction.

There is only one here, at least it seems so for me.

Algorithmic complexity can not be discussed separately from an... algorithm in mind. When you're talking about hash-table - as if you would consider any other data structure whatsoever - you have to be precise at least by the following points:

1. Best case, worst case or something in between?
2. Theoretical minimum or maximum or, again, something in between?
3. Particular operation on that data structure.

Let's talk about a lookup, i.e. something like `myHashTable['myKey']`, which also could be defined as `TVal getElementByKey<TVal, TKey>(HashTable<TKey, TVal> ht, TKey key)`; both examples are given in a pretty common modern pseudocode.

Normally an engineering is interested in knowing the worst case, since once your system/solution is prepared for that, it is automatically prepared for every other possible usage (which are better than the "worst" case by the definition). Thus, we will consider the worst case too.

A typical hash-table - the most simple "classical" you can imagine (also the one you're unlikely to meet in a real programming language standard library due to its oversimplicity) - would be an array of arrays or array of linked lists.

The first step then is to pick up the first index `i` and jump to it. RAM is known to be equally fast when you jump at whatever position, so jumping to the first memory slot and to the last one has no difference in costs. If that would not be the case, the whole algorithm would have a different cost too. But in order to jump to a correct `i` one has to perform hashing of a key - `'myKey'` in the example above. It is widely assumed that hashing does not depend upon input; while such an assumption is justified in many applications, it is plain wrong: hashing **does depend** upon a number of bits it has to transform. So, while hashing is at least linear in time, we take it to be constant - `O(1)`. Once we known the index `i`, jumping to it is also constant. This far we only did a constant amount of work (believing all the false assumptions we did).

What's next? Well, given `i`, we have another array storing `(key, value)` pairs in it. The next step is to search in this array for a record with key matching exactly `'myKey'` and once it is found, give it back or otherwise report that such a key does not exist. Thus, this problem reduces to a searching problem, for which different solutions are known. For example, given array is unordered, the best you could do is to have a `for` loop iteration all over the array and comparing current's record `.key` property with the given one. That would be a linear scan: at worst the required key does not exist there, so such an algorithm would have to get to the end of the array of some length `n` - that is, it would perform `O(n)` amount of constant work (once again, we assuming that comparing two keys together is constant, while in reality it is not: the longer `string`s to compare, the more characters one has to go over, so it can not be faster than linear; again, we fake it and ignore for simplicity!). However, given that the array is ordered, a simple binary search would be able to solve the problem much faster - in a logarithmic (base 2) number of compares! Hence, by getting to this point depending upon the data structure implementation once had to perform either `O(1) + O(n)` or `O(1) + O(log_2(n))` amount of work which is significantly different for big enough `n`. (**Important**: do not forget all the wrong assumptions made so far!).

---

Hopefully, at this point you can clearly see how inaccurate and how many inadequate assumptions a typical reasoning about algorithmic complexity could be or convey. I have to admit that it is possible to make it much more rigorous by explicitly providing a mathematical definition of `O(f)` for some function `f` and carefully considering every part of the entire algorithm. That would allow you to pick an arbitrary "constant factor" (comes from the mathematical definition I am intentionally omitting), which is nothing but an engineering nonsense from the practical perspective: one could choose such an enormous constant factor that it would take thousands of years to compute an algorithm - and that would be theoretically valid choice.

The lesson here is to develop a good theoretical and practical "senses" and be able to draw more or less clear borderline between the two. Both are needed to become a good software engineer; arguably, only the former one is required to be a good computer scientist.